# Why a 2D array can print out 1D, and how does const columns work in this code?

Tags: arrays, c

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
  for (int i =0; i< size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",arr[i];
  }
}
int main()
{
  int const columns = 3;
  int const rows = 2;
  int grades [][columns] = 
  {
    {12,23,45},
    {64,78,89}
  };
  for(int i =0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    printArray(grades[i],columns);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My question is, `int grades [][]` is a two-dimensional array, but in the `for` loop, `printArray (grades[],columns)`, the `grades[]` only has one `[]`.
Besides, columns is always 3 without changing 0,1,2... So how can it work?
Why this code can print out : 12 23 45 (\n) 64 78 89 , instead of : 45 89?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Technically, C does not have 2D arrays. It has arrays of arrays. With that in mind, `grades[i]` is just an array (here `int[columns]`) which happens to be exactly what `printArray` expects to get as first parameter.

Comment: @anatolyg Not really a duplicate and the answers aren't the best. Maybe if we leave this one open, a better answer will pop up.

Comment: "How can it work" is an unclear question (to me) — it just works, and I can't imagine a way it could be otherwise. Maybe explain your way of reasoning more clearly? Also, maybe try different dimensions — 2x3 is too small, allowing for confusion and off-by-one errors. Maybe try 2x5 instead of 2x3, and show what you would expect it to print?

Answer (score 0):

2D array is an array of 1D arrays. It is a continuous chunk of memory.

Arrays when used in expressions (as [rvalues](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=operators-lvalues-rvalues)) [decay do pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay).

When you call the function  `printArray(grades[i],columns);` the `grades[i]` 1D array deays to pointer to `int`.

Answer (score -2):

A 2-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays, more precisely, it contains their addresses.
`printArray` wants an array as input, `grades[i]` is an array so everything works fine.

Comment: The first part is correct, the second is not. 2D array does not contain addresses of the the 1D arrays only the arrays

Comment: This is not correct. If it contained its addresses, it would be an array of pointers which is something completely different. An array `int[x][y]` contains memory for `x*y` elements of type `int`. No pointers are involved.

Comment: Ok I might forgot something.

Comment: @sjmz it is a widespread beginner misunderstanding. Arrays decay and pointers can be confusing at the beginning

Comment: I think this answer is correct, except for a minor technicality. At least as far as I understand the question.